# Angularjs onkeypress update value from input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<td>{{count}}</td>
<td><div class="col-xs-12"><input type="text" ng-keypress="count ='10'" ng-init="count=0"></div></td>
```

Its working but I want to put the input text value into the count= to display the input value in the {{count}}
So if I write 20 into the input box the {{count}} must be 20 etc. But I dont know how to put the input text value into the ng-keypress without adding extra javascript parts.

Comment: do u want the value in the input box to get incremented to count or just show the exact same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `ng-model` directive on `input` element, That will enable two way binding and remove `ng-keypress` which isn't make sense there to have it.

```
<td>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
     <input type="text" ng-model="count" ng-init="count=0">
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried, but when I put in it nothing happens. I am testing http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-keydown here.

Comment: Thanks I missed a " from the row and thats why not worked.